# Dynamically changing the position of a button with respect to another button

Tags: android, android-widget

I had seen a couple of examples for setting the relative position through program (from java) for views in android. But in my particular case i have 2 buttons (which are not views) say "button_tag" and "button_rate" which are made via xml and are arranged such as "button_tag" above "button_rate" by default. If at any point of time is there a mechanism by which i can make "button_tag" below "button_rate" dynamically.

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button_tag"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
     android:background="@drawable/img_whitebackground"
     android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
     android:paddingLeft="5dip"
     android:text="@string/string_tag"
     android:onClick="click_addscreen" >
 </Button>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_rate"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/string_rate"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:onClick="click_addscreen"
    android:background="@drawable/img_whitebackground" >
</Button>
```

The xml part of the two buttons are as shown

Comment: They are in linear layout. Correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LayoutParams object and add rules to that object as per your requirement. and then setlayoutparam to your button.

For example:

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80,80); // size of button in dp
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.btnAdd);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 60);
            btnMyLocation.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add rules to set position dynamically.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button_rate);
buttonTag.setLayoutParams(p);
```