# How to retain state of activity after animation upon something like screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

So for example I use an object animator to change the alpha of a button to 0 and then I rotate the screen, then it's back to pre animated state because onCreate is called again. I was thinking I should implement something like an animation listener and at the end of the animation I should change the properties of the button, but I am not sure how to do that. For example if I have a constraint layout and I moved a button by 100 pixels up, what code should I have in the animation listener so that the change stays after the animation is over. I read something about setting the fill after tag to be true but I believe that is for view animations.

Thank You for the help.

Comment: just add  android:configChanges="orientation" in you manifest in the activity to which state you want to retain

Comment: @krishankTripathi everywhere I read by most google developers, they discourage retaining activity on rotation to preserve state. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335665/avoid-reloading-activity-with-asynctask-on-orientation-change-in-android/5336057#5336057)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the application you've described, you could use a `ValueAnimator` and set an `AnimatorUpdateListener` on it to record the state after each animation frame.

To listen for orientation changes and persist the state of the animation, you should first include `android:configChanges="orientation"` within the `<activity>` tag of your Manifest. This will ensure that your activity is not recreated on orientation change and that `onCreate()` won't be called again. Whenever an orientation change occurs, `onConfigurationChanged()` will be called, so you should override it to persist the animation state.

So, in your `onCreate()` you could do something like:

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new IntEvaluator(),
                            initialPosition, finalPosition);
valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        // mCurrentPosition should be a member variable 
        mCurrentPosition = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
        // Update the position of your button with currentPosition
    }
}
valueAnimator.start();
```

and your `onConfigurationChanged()` should look like:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);      
    // Set the position of your button with mCurrentPosition
}
```

For more info, please refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html.

Comment: But most articles(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335665/avoid-reloading-activity-with-asynctask-on-orientation-change-in-android/5336057#5336057) and [this](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)) explicitly state not to retain state of activity with android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: Ok, if you want to avoid that completely, then you can store the animation state in `SharedPreferences`, and then restore the state by loading the preference in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Alright, that should work thanks. Although I was expecting I had to do something like change layout params dynamically.

Comment: If you're changing the position of a button dynamically, you definitely will need to change the layout params. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31673553/2671503 for details

Comment: Would using constraint layout be not recommended in that case because the constraints would be messed up?

Comment: It should be fine to use a `ConstraintLayout`, but then you would need to use `ConstraintSet`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44361279/2671503